# Cause of a memory leak in C++ when using the Boehm GC

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

This code is causing a memory leak for me, and I'm not sure why.

[EDIT] Included code from [here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/91254/) into question:

```
#include "src/base.cpp"

typedef std::map<std::string, AlObj*, std::less<std::string>, 
  gc_allocator<std::pair<const std::string, AlObj*> > > KWARG_TYPE;

AlInt::AlInt(int val)   {
    this->value = val;
    this->setup();
}

// attrs is of type KWARG_TYPE
void AlInt::setup() {
    this->attrs["__add__"] = new AddInts();
    this->attrs["__sub__"] = new SubtractInts();
    this->attrs["__mul__"] = new MultiplyInts();
    this->attrs["__div__"] = new DivideInts();
    this->attrs["__pow__"] = new PowerInts();
    this->attrs["__str__"] = new PrintInt();
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        AlObj* a = new AlInt(3);
    }
}
```

AlInt inherits from AlObj, which in turn inherits from gc.  When I comment out the contents of setup() then I don't have a memory leak, this leads me to believe the issue is with the map not cleaning up, however I'm using the gc allocator, so I'm not sure where to look next.  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know much about C++, but isn't there supposed to be a return type specifier before `AlInt::Alint(int val) {`?

Comment: @zvoase: No, it is a constructor. Constructors and destructors do not have an explicit return type.

Answer (score 4):

The 'gc allocator' is allocating and looking after objects of this type:

```
std::pair<const std::string, AlObj*>
```

Just because this object has a pointer in it does not mean it the allocator will call delete on it.

If you want the object created in setUp() to be GC then you need to allocate them via the GC. Or learn to use boost:ptr_map or shared_ptr.

A map destroys (not deletes) the object it **owns**. In this case it owns the pointer **not** what the pointer points at. So when the map is destroyed it deallocates everything associated with the map and the object it owns (for pointers this means it does nothing).

If you have a map (or other container) that contains pointers. You must manually delete the pointers otherwise there will be a memory leak. Alternatively you can use boost::ptr_map or a map that contains a share_ptr

Comment: So I need a destructor on AlObj, that just does delete attrs?

Also, here's *all* the code: http://github.com/alex/alex-s-language/tree/local%2Fcpp-generation/alexs_lang/cpp if someone wants to take a peak.

Comment: Isn't the point of using the Boehm GC allocator that it will delete what the pointer points to when the map is destroyed?

Comment: Not quite. 'delete' will invoke the destructor of an object (which may release resources other than memory, file handles, for instance).

GC will simply reclaim memory which is no longer pointed to by any live pointers in your app.

Comment: So essentially I should create a destructor that iterates over attrs, and deletes each item?

Answer (score 0):

The allocator is deleting your pairs.  But deleting a pair doesn't delete members of the pair that happen to be pointers.

Comment: But surely it makes the members of the pair unreachable so they will be eligible for garbage collection?